# Android BluetoothGatt status code 128 BLE connection

Tags: android, connection

I'm trying to connect a BLE Device (Sigma chest strap) to my Sony Smartwatch 3 and the `writeDescriptor()` method fails to enable Notifications on the Device. The `onDescriptorWrite()` method displays the status code "128" which apparently stands for "GATT_NO_RESOURCES". Does anyone know what this error means or how to fix it?

Another BLE Device (Alpha Mio 2) works without any problems. descriptor is written and data received via onCharacteristicChanged().

```
Descriptor UUID: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 
Service UUID: 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Comment: I have encountered the same issue on a Nexus 5X with Android 7.0. There also seems to be a similar issue on Samsung S4 Mini with Android 4.4.2. Did you find a fix for it?